# Angular 2 - Bootstrap - Collapse

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

My question is, that how can I create own id for all collapse item ?

The problem is that if I click somewhere in the list always the first item gets collapsed. I try to give the div the data.id, but it doesn't works as well.

```
<div class="container">
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data">
  <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{data.id}}">{{data.subject}}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="{data.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">{{data.id}}</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">{{data.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in below line .

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{data.id}}">{{data.subject}}</a>
```

and  this line :

```
<div id="{data.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Curly bracket is missing here    `href="#{data.id}}` and here     `id="{data.id}}"`

Comment: np .. Enjoy ! :)